# IE 9 and lower Float Columns

Tags: internet-explorer-9, css-float

Have a look at http://store.auswidesaw.com.au/ This page displays correctly in Firefox, Chrome, Opera and even IE10 but in IE9 and lower the content all ends up in the left hand column. Can't work out the issue, any suggestions?

Comment: when I first pulled up the developers' tools in IE 10, it showed the document mode as 'Quirks mode.'  This is probably the culprit.  Try opening the tools in IE 9 using F12, and see what the document mode is

Comment: Put this at the top of the html: `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a doctype declaration, IE goes into Quirks mode.  Add a doctype to your page to get IE to play nicely with standards.

This is the html 5 version:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><!-- ... rest of html -->
</html>
```

Comment: Or rather, "plays less brokenly". IE7/8 still aren't great, but they are *downright broken* in Quirks Mode.

Comment: that is correct.  I just didn't want to break it to him while he's already down.